# How to compute symbolic computation of transfer function matrix?

Tags: matlab

Here I've a transfer function matrix with size of (3*7):

```
G  =  [G11,G12,G13,G14,G15,G16,G17;
       G21,G22,G23,G24,G25,G26,G27;
       G31,G32,G33,G34,G35,G36,G37]
```

Is it possible to get  `A = [G*(G^(-1))T]` symbolically in Matlab:
Where :

```
G^(-1) = inv(G) and (G^(-1))T = transpose of (inv(G))
```

Comment: Is `inv(G)` meant to represent a matrix inverse? If so, you'll need to use `pinv` as `G` isn't square. And does `G` just contain the symbolic variables you listed (i.e., `G = sym('G',[3 7])`) or is each one actually a transfer function? You should also specify if the elements of `G` are real or possibly complex.

Comment: Yes Gij are transfer functions and for simplicity I don't mentioned them here. Gij = a/(a*s+b) and a , b are differ for each columns and rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible but it may take a lot of time, and also it's possible that your computer runs out of memory. Matlab's symbolic operations are not very good, but here's the solution. First define the elements of your matrix as symbolic variables. `syms G11` defines `G11` as symbolic. than define your G matrix and go on. Than you can find the A matrix.

I should also mention that since your matrix is 3*7, I don't know if matlab have inverse command for non-square matrix, but you can have pseudo inverse. And if you want to do symbolic computations, Maple and mathematica are so much better. But matlab is better in Numerical computations .